# Find the $sin$ of an angle $B$ using law of sines given side angle side

Tags: trigonometry

this is giving me trouble, here's what I've tried:

Q.A triangle has sides $a=2$, $b=3$, and $\angle C = 60^o$. Using the law of sines, find $\sin(B)$

OK so I know the law of sines is: $$\frac{\sin(A)}{a}=\frac{\sin(B)}{b}=\frac{\sin(C)}{c}$$

so if I plug in what I know for now...$$\frac{\sin(A)}{2}=\frac{\sin(B)}{3}=\frac{\sin(60)}{c}$$

OK so then: $$\sin(B)=\frac{3\sin(60)}{c}$$

I also know that:$$\sin(B)=\frac{3\sin(A)}{2}$$

So then, $$\frac{3\sin(60)}{c}=\frac{3\sin(A)}{2}$$

Anyway I'm lost here, I don't really know what I'm supposed to do next. It feels circular. Please help nudge me in the right direction? explanations of WHY are always valuable. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe $sin(B)=\frac{3sin(A)}{2}$ is sufficient?  I'm guessing you cannot use the law of cosines.

Comment: I mean the book explicitly asks or me to use the law of sines, which is why I didn't attempt using law of cosines. I tried google, but all of the examples I saw were easier because you'd have A and a or B and b etc... as 2 of the 3 givens. Or else given 2 angles, which makes it too easy. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are allowed to use cosine rule, then you can find $c$ first and $B$ from there. otherwise, using sin rule you have ${3 \over \sin B} = {2 \over \sin(120^\circ - B)}$ which can be rearranged as 
$2 \sin B = 3\left(\sin(120^\circ) \cos B - \cos(120^\circ) \sin(B)\right)$
$= 3\left( \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\cos B + \frac{1}{2}\sin(B)\right).$

clearing all this gives $\tan(B) = 3\sqrt 3$ and $B = 79.106^\circ.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**

Analyse an equilateral triangle where a diagonal partitions the base into lengths of 1 and 2.
[image]

Something else that may be necessary (using the sine law of course) is to show that
$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$$